# seperate arrays and assign it to different parameters in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array where i am sending coordinates of a polygon. Each polygon consists of 4 points only. It is like as shown below

```json
{
  "Coordinates": {
    "Polygon": [
      [[30,75],[43,71],[48,95],[23,107]],
      [[76,53],[169,52],[147,89],[83,108]],
      [[30,75],[43,71],[48,95],[23,107]],
      [[76,53],[169,52],[147,89],[83,108]],
      [[178,67],[203,75],[194,134],[154,134]]
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to seperate out these polygon as shown below. How can i get it dynamically??

```json
{
  "Coordinates": {
    "Polygon": [[30,75],[43,71],[48,95],[23,107]],
    "Polygon1": [[76,53],[169,52],[147,89],[83,108]],
    "Polygon2": [[30,75],[43,71],[48,95],[23,107]],
    "Polygon3": [[178,67],[203,75],[194,134],[154,134]]
  }
}
```

Comment: Input array has 5 sub arrays or I'm wrong?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito sounds like index 1 and 3  have the same values, hence these are aggregated in the first occurrence. It's quite unclear though

Comment: @briosheje `1 equals 3` and `2 equals 4`. Either the output will contain `5` or `3`. How it is `4`?

Comment: @briosheje yes is unclear because he wants 4 sub arrays but input contains 5 arrays. I think the fourth sub array is a typo error.

Comment: Could you elaborate **why** you want this change? Accessing it as an array makes the most sense.

Comment: @decpk you're right, didn't see that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired structure in the following manner:

```js
const object = {
  "Coordinates": {
    "Polygon": [
      [[ 30, 75],[ 43, 71],[ 48, 95],[ 23,107]],
      [[ 76, 53],[169, 52],[147, 89],[ 83,108]],
      [[ 30, 75],[ 43, 71],[ 48, 95],[ 23,107]],
      [[ 76, 53],[169, 52],[147, 89],[ 83,108]],
      [[178, 67],[203, 75],[194,134],[154,134]]
    ]
  }
};

// In the line below `...object` is optional if `object` only
// contains the key `Coordinates` and no other keys.
const result = { ...object, Coordinates: {} };
object.Coordinates.Polygon.forEach((coords, i) => {
  result.Coordinates[`Polygon${i}`] = coords;
});

console.log(result);
```

However I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here. This change in structure changes access to a single "polygon" from `object.Coordinates.Polygon[0]` to  `result.Coordinates.Polygon0`.

Since the collection of polygons is no longer an array but an object, you also lose the ability to use array methods like `map`, `filter` etc. which are all pretty useful.

Comment: ```result.Coordinates[`Polygon${i === 0 ? '' : i}`] = coords``` - if you want to avoid the Polygon0

Comment: @Sam True. I didn't do that in this answer since you would create a strange exception for yourself where a single property has no number where all others do. Shorter would be `result.Coordinates[\`Polygon${i || ''}\`] = coords`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Math.ceil` to find the middle index and then use a `splice` in this way:

```js
var input = {"Coordinates":{"Polygon":[[[30,75],[43,71],[48,95],[23,107]],[[76,53],[169,52], 
[147,89],[83,108]],[[30,75],[43,71],[48,95],[23,107]],[[178,67],[203,75],[194,134],[154,134]]]}}

const list = input.Coordinates.Polygon.flat(1);
const index = Math.ceil(list.length / 4);

let result = {"Coordinates":{}};

for(let i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
 if(i === 0) result.Coordinates.Polygon = list.splice(-index);
 else result.Coordinates["Polygon" + i] = list.splice(-index);
}
console.log(result)
```